# Relation between User field and current user

Tags: views, entities, users

I have created a view for particular user role (i.e: Agent) that manage some user (for example, users with id: 1, 2, 3).

I've created a custom field for this user for associate this agent with some users.

It's possible create view who allow of this agent view, edit, ecc only content created by users who managed by him?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to add a relationship in views to your custom field you created and then provide a default value of "User ID from logged in user"